# Android: change application theme in java

Tags: java, android, themes

I'm trying to build a multiTheme application.
I want set theme of whole of application in java code. It can be set in XML in this way in Manifest file:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/myTheme" >
```

I store the selected theme ID in SharedPreferences.
I have tried the following code in my launcher activity:

```
getApplicationContext().setTheme(R.style.mainTheme2); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_selection);
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
getApplication().setTheme(R.style.mainTheme2);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_selection)  ;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
setTheme(R.style.mainTheme2);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_selection)  ;
```

The last code change the activity theme, but not the application theme!
others does not change anything!

How can i change the application theme in java codes?!

Answer (score 2):

When the theme changed you stored it probably somewhat similar to this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("theme", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putInt("resId", R.style.Theme_AppCompat).commit();
```

When you stored the currently selected theme ID in `SharedPreferences` the only thing you have to do is read the value in `onCreate` of any `Activity` that you want to respect this theme like so:

```
public class ThemedActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // read current custom theme from preferences
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("theme", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int resId = prefs.getInt("resId", R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);
    setTheme(resId);

    // business as usual
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
  }
}
```

If you want to apply the theme immediately to current activity restart it after you make changes to the `SharedPreferences`:

```
startActivity(getIntent()); // this comes first to ensure valid context
finish();
```

Comment: I have mentioned to this code in my question!!! this just change the theme of one activity!!! I want change the APPLICATION THEME !

Comment: Sadly you cannot change the application or activity themes as defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`, those values are final.
However the code above makes it possible for you to store selected theme ID in preferences and then the activity reads this theme ID from preference before it starts.
If you want more activities to behave this way, you need to include the "theme reading" lines in those too.